# Таблица в javaFX, печать

Tags: java, javafx, print

Имеется вот такая таблица: [image: Таблица JavaFX]

Нужно её распечатать. Пробую через PrinterJob. Печатает, но только печатает так, как выглядит на экране. Как можно её распечатать, чтобы она была на весь А4 и, если не поместилась на один лист, часть таблицы была перенесена на 2й лист. Читал JAVA doc, там есть пример печати таблицы, но на Swing. Как такое можно сделать на javaFX? 
[ссылка на JavaDOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html)
очень рассчитываю на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать `snapshot` всей таблицы, а дальше, в зависимости от настроек для ширины столбцов и общей ширины получившейся таблицы - порезать "картинку таблицы" на куски, удобно помещающиеся на формат **A4** (29.7 x 21 см- 1754 x 1240 пикселей (**150dpi**) 3510 x 2480 пикселей ( **300 dpi**)), в зависимости от выбранного разрешения.
Ну и нарезанные картинки отправить в очередь печати.

Comment: А есть способ без создания скриншотов? Бьюсь уже который день над этим

Comment: Конечное представление при печати всё равно будет в виде "скриншота". Так что, просто попробуйте сделать snapshot элемента и аккуратно его порезать.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Попробую!

Comment: И ещё появился вопрос. Имеет ли право на жизнь такой вот метод: на экран выводить эту таблицу, а на печать отправлять таблицу базы данных? И можно ли распечатать таблицу, допустим, mySQL?

Comment: Всё зависит от реализации. Таблица в БД - это по сути файлик. Вы делаете из него выборку, данные извлекаются из файла или структуры в памяти компьютера и преобразуются в некоторый (текстовый, например, но не обязательно) формат. Отформатированные данные так или иначе выводятся в каком-то виде (текстовое подобие таблицы, простой текст с разделителями, электронная таблица, которая по сути является картинкой, которую рендерит система в определённом месте экрана, и т.д.) на экран. Принтер можно воспринимать как "особенный экран", на который Вы может вывести только один кадр.

Comment: Соответственно, можно вывести на печать что угодно, главное, чтобы это что угодно можно было перевести в некую растровую графику, которую принтер сможет превратить в матрицу точек различных цветов на поверхности листа бумаги.